# Typescript gives intersection instead of union when using nested properties and dynamic execution

Tags: typescript

I am currently wrestling with Typescript in order to type my config which is used throughout my application. The config is of type Config and it is held in an object using key-values. By use of a helper function I define types of the function argument.

```
// Base object types
export type Config<D> = {
  fn: ({ option }: { option: D }) => any;
  option: D;
};

export type ConfigRecord<T extends Record<keyof T, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Config<T[K]> & { type: K };
};

// Helper function to type function argument
export const typeConfigRecord = <T extends Record<keyof T, any>>(
  map: ConfigRecord<T>
) => map;

// Actual implementation of type
const configRecord = typeConfigRecord({
  test: {
    type: "test",
    fn: ({ option }) => {
      return option;
    },
    option: "test",
  },
  test2: {
    type: "test2",
    fn: ({ option }) => {
      return option;
    },
    option: 2,
  },
});
```

Now calling the config using the following method works, and the argument type is inferred correctly:

```
configRecord.test.fn({ option: "test" });
```

But when I dynamically execute the function as follows instead of a union the function argument becomes an intersection of all possible values, causing it to error:

```
const dynamicExecute = (type: keyof typeof configRecord) => {
  const config = configRecord[type];

  return config.fn({ option: config.option }); // Error, type is never
}
```

I already researched and saw the term correlated unions, I tried figuring out what is going wrong here but I am thinking that because it is a nested property it is tripping me up. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is essentially a correlated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) issue as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The compiler cannot analyze the single block of code

```
const config = configRecord[type];
return config.fn({ option: config.option });
```

where `config` is of a union type, and see that `{option: config.option}` is correlated with `config.fn` in just the right way so that they match.  Instead it just treats both `{option: config.option}` and `config.fn` as independent union types, so you're passing a union of arguments to a union of functions, and that's not safe.  I mean, if you have `config1` and `config2` of the same union type, you couldn't call `config1.fn({option: config2.option})` safely, and because the compiler tracks only the *types* here and not the *identities* of `config` vs `config1`/`config2`, it can't tell the difference between them.

---

The recommended approach in cases like this is to switch from unions to [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  There is a fairly involved technique detailed in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), but the first step is to replace the union type with a generic type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to that union.

If you do that here, things just work:

```
const dynamicExecute = <K extends keyof typeof configRecord>(type: K) => {
  const config = configRecord[type];
  return config.fn({ option: config.option }); // okay
}
```

That's because the types you have are essentially already in the proper form (a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over a basic key-value interface) as described in ms/TS#47109, and the only thing you were missing was to use generics.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/PTAECEEMGcFNQPYCMBWsDGAXUmCeAHWaAKFgA98EAnbPQ0AYQQDsAzASwHMAeAEQD5QAXlABvYqFCtmALlAAKUYnyZ2LUAF85ShCrWzQvTQEphgyM1wBuCctUs5vGxpukK1WgXhM2XAEoY1AAm3AAqoOSYsMxB0KAB6MHcANawuAisoKEANKAWuPyCIuKSANoA0qDszKCp6ZmhALpyPhw8oRWNggBkYjhecpUuxMPEIKAAErAANoRUUgCuzFj6OAj99KxLK+qQVJwLALbRmG6UNKCJzNCehK3+gVRBwqBhEWRRMXEJSXUZWbl8oV5LZDpB8C0WG0fk8wvxiKYhIIwfhXOMAIJYBaQaZVQ74aawY7MTCQew1f50WDEK43S5Qh6JJ4vKn3TgwoKKWxRG7aWySKlyABEPMwQuy-KkBkUdlWGkRghKkmVVFgmAWVApehYNmVmglet05OFovFtg0BpwREwACY+XrBaARdabWa9dI5DKjXKFWJJZJVerNbKdZKLZLvQ5QDbLeH5a4rtDHkEAHSilPSL3agzOm5CkyuGksOlBXDMSCHdjoACiZAwCyiL24lUi0VitTSlK8-0TjOC-HkjvKvqVtOwvc4LwnHNKVMautAgY1NQnGeYWeN9N8nBTkZq8dA4wQyUguBGxGIQA)